# Inverse hyperbolic functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am attempting to learn inverse hyperbolic functions but I can't even follow the examples in the book. The example is $y= \sinh y = \frac{e^y - e^{-y}}2$ they they make it into $e^y -2x - e^{-y} = 0$ I don't really understand what is going on, are inverses equal to x? I just don't follow what he did there at all. There just isn't much explanation here, or at least enough for me to figure it out.

Comment: That should read $x = \mathrm{sinh} y$, so that $y=\mathrm{sinh}^{-1} x$ (the inverse hyperbolic sine function) is what you're solving for. And what they did is basically multiply both sides of the equation by $2$ and then move everything onto one side.

Comment: I stared at it for about 10 minutes and couldn't figure that out...either I am stupid or they should have just added that step.

Comment: Jordan, you shouldn't have to apologize or call yourself stupid. Maybe you are doomed to be forever bad at math, or maybe you have a lot more potential and just can't find the right rhythm - I don't have an answer to that. But it seriously pains me to see you beating yourself up all the time.

Comment: ...and it's certainly unhealthy to be frequently, repeatedly calling yourself "stupid". Things like those, repeated enough, are self-fulfilling. You need to change that habit if you don't want to be forever stuck.

Answer (score 3):

The text of the question is not clear, and I am a few miles away from my copy of *Stewart*.  But I imagine that the calculation goes something like this. Suppose that 
$$x=\sinh y= \frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}.$$
We want to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. The first thing to do is to multiply both sides by $2$, so we won't have to carry fractions around. They are heavy.

So we get $2x=e^y-e^{-y}$.  Now we can do one of several things.  Maybe rewrite $e^{-y}$ as $1/e^y$.  So now we have
$$2x=e^y -\frac{1}{e^y}.$$ 
It will save typing, and be useful in other ways, to let $w=e^y$.
We obtain 
$$2x=w -\frac{1}{w}.$$
Multiply both sides by $w$.  We get $2xw=w^2-1$.  Rearrange this equation a little. We get 
$$w^2-2xw-1=0.$$
This is a quadratic equation in $w$. The solutions are, by the Quadratic Formula,
$$w=\frac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2+4}}{2}=x \pm\sqrt{x^2+1}.$$
Now we remember that $w=e^y$, so 
$$e^y=x \pm\sqrt{x^2+1}.$$
But note that $e^y$ is always *positive*, and $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is negative.
So the solution with the minus sign has to be rejected, and 
$$e^y=x + \sqrt{x^2+1}.$$
Take the natural logarithm ($\ln$) of both sides. We get
$$y=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right).$$

Comment: How do I take the natural logarithm of a number?

Comment: @Jordan: The line in which Andre took the natural logarithm doesn't have a specific number, it has an expression. In order to represent taking the natural logarithm of it, you put $\ln()$ around it. This "undoes" the exponential function, so taking the natural logarithm of $e^y$ returns plain old $\text{ }y$.

Comment: I don't know why I just can't wrap my head around that concept. So if I am taking loge of $e^y$ it is going to give me y because whatever is making e y will also make the ln y? Also what if I don't have x as a value, what if the value is 5 so I have 5 = sinh inverse?

Comment: Remember, this is one of the standard facts I said in another post comes  up over and over, and has to become automatic: $\ln(e^u)=u$.

Comment: I don't follow the quadratic part at all.

Comment: You can actually just spot the answer the inverse hyperbolic cosine of $1$, without needing any algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing $y = \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$, so $y = \sinh x$, not $y= \sinh y$.

$$
\begin{align}
y & = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} \\  \\
2y & = e^x + e^{-x}  \\  \\
0 & = e^x + e^{-x} - 2y
\end{align}
$$
If you multiply both sides of this by $e^x$, you get
$$
0 = \left(e^x\right)^2 + 1 - 2ye^x,
$$
so
$$
0 = u^2 + 1 - 2yu
$$
and you've got a quadratic equation in $u$
$$
au^2 + bu + c = 0,
$$
where $a=1$, $b=-2y$, and $c=1$.

Comment: I believe you have the $y$ and $x$ backwards.